# Authorizing discord bot to read a user's servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Hey what's popping lads

I'm looking for how to authorize a discord bot to access what servers a person is in. This is using discordjs. I've tried to find some tutorials and tried to learn off of other bots that have done this, but can't really find out how to do it.

Thank you in advance <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get what servers a person is in, for privacy reasons.

Comment: But for something like this (this is someone else's bot, don't accept or whatever) https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=264434993625956352&scope=identify&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftop.gg%2Flogin%2Fcallback&response_type=code , they're able to access things about the person's account. I also looked on this thing called OAuth2 under the bot section, doesn't it say that you can see someone's guilds?

Comment: It asks for "Access your username and avatar" wich is the `identify` scope.

Here's the list of available scopes : https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes

Maybe what you wants was the `guilds` scope ? 

A bot can ask